# how to wait for puppeteer to complete a print to printer function?

Tags: puppeteer

I am running puppeteer in `kiosk-printing` mode to automate the printing of PDF to the printer.  But I have to use `waitForTimeout` to give the printer sufficient time to, I guess, receive the print instructions. Otherwise, `browser.close( )` shuts puppeteer down too quickly, and nothing prints.

How to wait for the print function to complete?  I am not sure what the arbitrary `waitForTimeout` value should be.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () =>
{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
      headless: false, 
      "args": [ "--kiosk-printing" ]
    });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`file:///C:/Users/srich/Downloads/packing-list.pdf`);

  await page.evaluate(() => { window.print(); });
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000) ;

  await browser.close( ) ;
})();
```

I tried to `goto` a web page after running `window.print`. Then wait for that navigation to complete. But the shutdown of puppeteer still came too quickly and the PDF did not print.

```js
  await page.evaluate(() => { window.print(); });
  await page.goto(`https://google.com`);
  await page.waitForSelector('input'); 
  await browser.close( ) ;
```

Comment: the problem is `--kiosk-printing` cannot be awaited within `page.evaluate`. the evaluate method only awaits the promise of `window.print` then node steps to the next step immediately. is puppeteer mandatory in your use case, or you only need it to open pdf files? asking because there are more lightweight node packages to print pdf.

Comment: I am open to any solution.  A node package is ideal.  I can automate printing with adobe acrobat from the command line. But that leaves the adobe app open. And I have been told about Nitro.  One worry I have is that I will not be able to control the printer settings. In windows, there is a "scale: fit to printable area" setting that works well.  When printing with puppeteer I only get the default settings.

Comment: using the pdf-to-printer node package.  looks good.